# Is it possible to have optional return type from class method based on optional class parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm having troubles with types based on optional class parameter in constructor:

```js
type Config<Result> = {
  foo: string;
  bar?: () => Result;
};

class ClassWithOptionalParameter<Result> {
  constructor(private config: Config<Result>) {}

  someMethod() {
    if (this.config.bar) {
      return this.config.bar();
    }

    return "some string";
  }
}

const withObject = new ClassWithOptionalParameter({
  foo: "number",
  bar: () => ({ property: "anything" }),
});
const obj = withObject.someMethod(); // should have type '{ property: string; }', not 'some string" | { property: string; }'
console.log(obj.property); // Property 'property' does not exist on type '"some string" | { property: string; }'

const withNumber = new ClassWithOptionalParameter({ foo: "number", bar: () => 123.456 });
const num = withNumber.someMethod(); // should have type '{ property: string; }', not 'number | "some string"'
console.log(num.toPrecision(4)); // Property 'toPrecision' does not exist on type 'number | "some string"'

const withString = new ClassWithOptionalParameter({ foo: "string" });
const str = withString.someMethod(); // should have type 'string', not 'unknown'
console.log(str.charAt(1)); // 'str' is of type 'unknown'.
```

As you can see from example in cases when I provide `bar` parameter `someMethod` returns intersection of `Result` and `some string` types although it should be just `Result` type.
And in case when there is no `bar` parameter return type is `unknown`.

I created [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAShAzgVwBtgA+KAXigG8AoKKJOOALil2ACcUE0BuOqACMAhhwD8rABQBKCmRwFi-AL78aAY0LDcuWFp0B1FMAAWAeTDAUiYYQAKo4QFsIwCB2x4ipagPWJ2Dnx1YDgOSTAuADdhNyh-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-kHYE1lYokyS3eiqUCPdTBYpUOlZE9OWQy9rxFMVU0lbVWLVWNpXwBAAGtPxOBBgLtB0nRdSRAlaEUOAAQWASRpyQlUL20jgIyaak6lI-SjJMszmiAA) to see it in details.

I tried to add return type for `someMethod` but received another error:

```
type ReturnType<Result> = Config<Result> extends { bar: unknown } ? string : Result;

class ClassWithOptionalParameter<Result> {
  constructor(private config: Config<Result>) {}

  someMethod(): ReturnType<Result> {
    if (this.config.bar) {
      return this.config.bar();
    }

    return "some string"; // `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Result'. 'Result' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.`
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no compiler-verified safe way to do this; you'd need [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) or [ms/TS#56315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56315) or both. Personally I'd just use a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nloorw) and move on. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Got it, thanks. I think I got the idea but your explanation could be helpful as well.

Comment: It's been quite a while since I posted this and I've essentially forgotten about it. If I write up an answer, would you commit to responding in a timely manner, like, within a day or to?